# Passing authentication details with a JSON-RPC call

Tags: go

I haven't been able to find any documentation on this. I need to make JSON-RPC calls to an API that requires (basic) authentication details to be passed, but can't find any way to do this with the standard `net/rpc/jsonrpc` package. A clipped version of my non-authenticating code is below.

```
var reply string
netClient, _ = net.Dial("tcp", "localhost:1234")
jsonClient = jsonrpc.NewClient(netClient)
jsonClient.Call("someMethod", someArgs, &reply)
```

Comment: I've never used jsonrpc, but just by reading the docs it looks like ClientCodec is what you need to accomplish this.

Comment: is it http://www.jsonrpc.org/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Basic-Auth is an HTTP concept. Your code is opening a "raw" TCP connection to `localhost:1234`. What you need is an HTTP transport layer underneath.

There's two ways to accomplish what you want: either implement an HTTP-speaking `io.ReadWriteCloser` and use as in your example or implement an `rpc.ClientCodec` that does the HTTP basic auth and use in conjunction with `rpc.NewClientWithCodec`.