# How to perform authentication of RPC server&client by HTTP in Go?

Tags: authentication, go, rpc

I'm new to GO and I'm following https://parthdesai.me/articles/2016/05/20/go-rpc-server/ to build a simple RPC server&client. In this article, it says

> Benefit of this approach (HTTP) is, you can perform authentication of client easily, before allowing RPC, using any authentication method supported by HTTP.

But the example on the page doesn't seem to perform it. I have searched it on StackOverflow, and found [Passing authentication details with a JSON-RPC call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50621335/passing-authentication-details-with-a-json-rpc-call) saying

> There's two ways to accomplish what you want: either implement an HTTP-speaking `io.ReadWriteCloser` and use as in your example or implement an `rpc.ClientCodec` that does the HTTP basic auth and use in conjunction with `rpc.NewClientWithCodec`.

However, I still don't know how to do it. Could I have some example code (may be `Basic Authentication` method)?

Comment: I think the basic auth the page said is like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16673766/basic-http-auth-in-go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using transcoding and checking authentication in gRPC middleware is better for http server over gRPC using [gRPC gateway](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway).

https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/transcoding

To get authorization in headers, use gRPC middleware and get from context with gRPC MD.

```golang
srv := grpc.NewServer(exampleJwtMiddleware())

func exampleJwtMiddleware() grpc.UnaryServerInterceptor {
    return func(ctx context.Context, req interface{}, info *grpc.UnaryServerInfo, handler grpc.UnaryHandler) (resp interface{}, err error) {

        token, err := extractHeaderFromContext(ctx, "Authorization")
        // do sometings...
        return handler(ctx, req)

    }
}

func extractHeaderFromContext(ctx context.Context, header string) ([]string, error) {
    md, ok := metadata.FromIncomingContext(ctx)
    if !ok {
        return nil, ERROR_NO_HEADER_IN_REQUEST
    }

    foundedHeaders, ok := md[header]
    if !ok {
        return nil, ERROR_NO_HEADER_IN_REQUEST
    }

    return foundedHeaders, nil
}
```